# NLS in R, coefficient by row

Tags: r, nls, estimation

I am trying to solve for k, in the hyperbolic model below, for each row in my dataframe instead of getting an overall estimate using all data. Each variable (delay, indifference) is already in the dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
nls(indifference ~100/(1+(delay*k)), data = refactor, start = list(k=1))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(refactor)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(refactor, 20))`.